# HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader() not setting Content-Type header

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, httpresponse

I'm using third-party software to render PDFs from html documents. I created a small test project and using the `OnClick` event of an `<asp:Button>` I was able to read a html document from a directory and render it as a PDF with no problems.

The response is created as follows:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    String.Format("{0}; filename=Test.pdf;", "inline" ));
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

When I look at the response in Chrome, I can see that Content-Type is being set correctly:

> Content-Disposition:inline; filename=HtmlToPdf.pdf;
>
> Content-Length:101482
>
> Content-Type:application/pdf

I've tried to transfer the above to my current project. The only difference being that instead of one `<asp:Button>` I'm using a custom button inside a DevExpress grid view. I Initially handled the custom button click in a callback panel, but Content-Type was not being set. Viewing the response in Chrome proved this:

> Content-Disposition:inline; filename=5.pdf;
>
> Content-Encoding:gzip
>
> Content-Length:149015
>
> Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8

I've also tried using the `gvDocuments.CustomButtonCallback += new ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventHandler(gvDocuments_CustomButtonCallback);` event but Content-Type is still not being set.

Anyone have any ideas as to why I cannot set Content-Type in the above scenario?

Comment: Does the PDF still look OK? It appears that something in IIS's pipeline is applying compression, have you tried disabling that?

Comment: It doesn't even render. The response is a 200 OK, but Content-Type is text/plain. I'm debugging locally so it's with VS Development Server. Would there be any reason why it shouldn't be getting set in a callback/ grid view custom button click event?

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
```

> response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + yourFileName + ".pdf");
stream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Resp As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
Resp.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options")
Resp.AppendHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")
```

By adding the above lines in the page load/init method will add  http response header.