# Change Content-Type for SqlQuery result

Tags: c#, json, content-type, asp.net-apicontroller

I am making from a ApiController a direct SQL query (SQL Server 2014) to the DB:

```
    public object Post(JObject jsonData){
//..
 string qvalue = "SELECT s.Id, v.[Name] VehicleId, s.TimestampLocal FROM Status s INNER JOIN Vehicles v on s.VehicleId = v.Id";
     var resl = entities.Database.SqlQuery<StatusTime>(qvalue);
     return resl;
```

The response arrives to the client as Content-Type: "application/json; charset=utf-8". I want to change the Content-Type to something else like: "application/json" or even "text/xml".

I have tried adding before "return resl;" the line: 
`HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";`
but it does not change it.

I have tried adding something to the header (just to see the response changed) and the header is changed (and arrives at the client changed) with:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("test", "hello");
```

I have seen this example: 
[HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader() not setting Content-Type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196405/httpcontext-current-response-addheader-not-setting-content-type-header)

and indeed it sets the content type but I have no idea how to apply it to a SqlQuery result. Also I do not want to bring the data to the IIS server with .ToList or similar and then write it to the response because it is massive (~80MB).

I have seen this too:
[WebAPI to Return XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662028/webapi-to-return-xml)

and: [Change Content-Type header for HttpResponseMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361075/change-content-type-header-for-httpresponsemessage)

How could this be done, or is this decided for me by the controller?

Comment: The `charset` is probably there as a part of the response encoding.  Does your config file specify a `responseEncoding`?

Comment: It may be constructive for you to say what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.  What is the problem with the default content type for the return of an object?  I am just wondering if you are asking the right question.

Comment: @btberry I am trying to fix this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139957/jquery-ajax-response-undefined-with-internet-explorer The content is successfully downloaded in Chome, Firefox and even in IE (for a small dataset <15MB). After that IE downloads all the content (response 200 even for 100MB+) but the data is undefined. I hope changing the content-type will solve the issue.

Comment: @stephen.vakil no I did not specify a responseEncoding in web.config. One of the  references in my post actually says that the type is set automatically by  the apicontroller if i return a serializable object.